# Automated UITest strategy for 2 mobile applications - User app/Admin app

Tags: jenkins, mobile, automated-tests, xamarin.uitest

I am on a development team where we have 2 separate mobile apps. One of the apps is for Users. The other app is for Admin of those users. My main objective is to execute a test case in the Admin app, *and then* run a test case in the Users app to verify its working properly. How can I approach this?

For example, I want to run a test case in the Admin app that revokes some privilege. I then want to run a test case from the Users app to check to confirm that privilege was revoked.

Maybe this is not a good strategy at all -- but it makes sense for my team because we have 2 apps that work together -- and if we do some function in the Admin app -- we want to see the expected result in the Users app

My plan was to mark each test with a Category, for example, "Privilege"

On Jenkins:

1. Run "Privilege" Category on the Admin app where I revoke some privilege
2. Run  "Privilege" Category on the User app where I confirm revoked privilege

This seems like an ok test strategy right now. But if I have 20 UITests that means I'll have 20 different Jenkins projects in my dashboard, one for each UITest (per device, per platform). It seems that with 20 UITests I'll end up with over 100 Jenkins projects. Thats not really ideal to me.

Has anybody else come up with a testing strategy where they needed to test 2 separate projects back and forth. I understand that this does not really fall under unit testing - and I may get some vague answers around unit testing and general. But I do believe mobile is a different animal in the UITest world

Comment: Hey, I understand your problem here. What are you using for the automated tests currently? That might help come up with a solution here. My idea would be to make each test dependent on one another. So you would force the second scenario to run after the first. You hopefully would not need another jenkins job to run the second scenario.

Comment: I'm using the Xamarin platform so my UITests are Xamarin UITests running on a mac with a suite of devices plugged in. We have a Job that does an App Build and then deploys the app onto the devices. After that, another Job named something 'UserAppUITests-iPhoneX' will run, and then 'UserAppUITests-iPhone7' will run and so forth. But YES, I'm trying to bring another app into the mix but want to organize into different categories but I feel like I would end up with way too many Jenkins Jobs and it would be come a spaghetti mess, and unmanageable unless we hire a full time automation tester

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of points in your question

> do some function in the Admin app -- we want to see the expected result in the Users app

If you need to test such integrations between the two apps, you can go with proper labels for ones that are

> mark each test with a Category

in any case, you will need some way to organise your suites. Good way to do so, are [test annotations](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/Android.Test.Suitebuilder.Annotation/). I think [Lazy setup](http://xunitpatterns.com/Lazy%20Setup.html) is aplicable  in your case. It will set the desired state for all marked tests, when needed.

> needed to test 2 separate projects back and forth

End-to-end tests are mandatory, for the most business critical features. My suggestion is to employ [Backdoor manipulation](http://automationisking.blogspot.com/2015/10/back-door-manipulation-api-layer.html). Your other tests should already have covered the simpler cases (e.g. setting a privilege in Admin app), so if you already did exercise this feature, no point of redundancy.

> It seems that with 20 UITests I'll end up with over 100 Jenkins projects. Thats not really ideal

You actually don't need a Jenkins project per suite, just configure the tests via CLI arguments and your harness will pick that up for you. What you need is a tag (or platform, or device) to be passed to the runner.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you do *NOT* want tests to depend on each other. Have a look at this example:

1. In the admin app, you set the privilege.
2. You open the user app.
3. The privilege should be set, but it's not.

You know that something went wrong, but you don't know whether it's the admin app that's not working or the user app.

Therefore, you should test them independently by mocking (=faking) the backend:

1. Open the admin app.
2. Set the privilege.
3. Ask the mocked backend: Did you receive a call from the admin app to set the privilege?

In an independent UI test for the user app, you do the following:

1. Set up a fake backend where the privilege is set
2. Open the user app
3. See whether the privilege is set.

By separating the tests for both apps, you will know which of the two does not work.

The software that I use at work to do such things is called [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/) but there are others out there, too.

Comment: My problem is that I really do not want to use mock objects. My main objective here is end-to-end testing. My mobile team relies on an API managed by another team. When they make a change in some environment we want our Apps to kick off using real data, testing a real environment. Of course there are API unit tests and other tools we have in place already but we still need to smoke test both our apps. I understand your argument for Mock and Unit testing though